# LNK4204 warning and D3D file loading crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010

About a month ago, I started to dive into Frank Luna's "Introduction to 3d Programming with Directx11". I had no problems up until now and have made it through a good chunk of the book. Recently, I had to switch computers and started by setting up the first demo in the book to make sure everything was properly configured. I set this demo up on my old computer about a month ago with no issues, now I can't even get this basic demo to run on the new computer. I'm unsure whether the warnings are related to the crash or not.

Warnings are as follows:

```
            1>     Creating library C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\test.lib and object C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\test.exp
            1>Effects11d.lib(d3dx11dbg.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(d3dxGlobal.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectLoad.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectNonRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectReflection.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>LinkEmbedManifest:
            1>     Creating library C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\test.lib and object C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\test.exp
            1>Effects11d.lib(d3dx11dbg.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(d3dxGlobal.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectLoad.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectNonRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectReflection.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>Effects11d.lib(EffectRuntime.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\vc100.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
            1>  test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Rizzmond\Desktop\test\Debug\test.exe
```

The crash is from the D3D11CompileFromFile returning a D3D11_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when trying to load a file. I have set this demo up exactly as I did before so I cannot fathom why it is unable to load this "color.fx" file. You can see the relevant code and the solution explorer in a picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKCW5.jpg

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but when trying to open files with VC I get an error "There was a problem sending the command to the program". However, if I open up VC first then open the file there is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when debug version of a library is linked to the project, but corresponding debug database file (.pdb) is not accessible. You need to re-build Effects11d.lib from sources to generate .pdb on your new computer. Sources of the library are reported to be available: http://www.d3dcoder.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=241

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem

```
---------------------------
Unexpected error encountered
---------------------------
File: d:\3dgameprogramming\code\chapter 6 drawing in direct3d\box\boxdemo.cpp
Line: 310
Error Code: D3D11_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (0x887c0002)
Calling: D3DX11CompileFromFile
Do you want to debug the application?
---------------------------
```

the problem is: D3DX11CompileFromFile() unable to find "fx\color.fx",
just copy "....\Code\Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D\Box\FX" to the same directory as the executable file. 
And no need to recompile.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhHxU.png)